# How should I remove carpet in preparation for sanding and polishing floorboards?

Tags: flooring, carpet, removal

I have a bedroom I want to convert into a nursery.  The room's mostly carpeted, with a small section missing where a wardrobe was built in.  From what I can see, it's just carpet over floorboards, no glue.  I'm guessing there are tack strips on the perimeter.  Before we bought the house, the house inspector said the floorboards were in perfect condition.

I want to have polished floorboards in the room, due to allergen issues.

I have next to no renovation experience, but I'm keen to start doing things myself.  Is there anything in particular I should be watching out for?

I'll leave the sanding/polishing for a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull up the edges around the perimeter, roll up the carpet and dispose. If working yourself, cut the carpet into manageable sections you can carry.  There might be padding under the carpet but its probably not tacked down.  Cut and roll it up too.

Use a small pry bar to pull up the tack strips and make sure to remove or hammer down any nails that are not sitting flush with the floor.  If there are stubborn nails, place a small scrap of wood under the pry bar so that you don't damage the floor.

Comment: Great, looks perfect.  I'll be able to confirm in a few days.  Cheers Steven.